# Sharepoint 2013 - Filter Query Builder results by site column value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within my search results web part in SharePoint, I went into the web part properties, and opened up Query Builder.  The following query works awesome in Query Builder...

```
{SearchBoxQuery} MyDocTagsOWSTEXT:chart
```

..as it finds all items in my document library that has "chart" text associated to the MyDocTags column. So how can I make this live?  What left do I need to do, to always have **{SearchBoxQuery}** filter results based on **MyDocTagsOWSTEXT**???

My SharePoint search box and search results web parts are both on the same publishing page.

I feel like I am so close! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code when you build your query in search results web part,

```
MyDocTagsOWSTEXT:{SearchBoxQuery}
```

Comment: Dude you are the man!!!!!  Outside of breaking a display template a part and modifying more custom settings, query builder is such an awesome way to keep the UI running as is, and simply managing all the search processing through a single web part for custom results!  I love it!